# Whats wrong with my session code

Tags: php, html, session, syntax

Can you please assit me guys, am learning the concept of sessions which is to help me in user loging in. I did the following php code but am getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\w3\login.php on line 12.

```
<?php
    session_start();
        echo "      <html>
                    <body>
                    <br/>
                    <table border = '0'  width = '100%' height = '100%'><tr>
                    <td width = '30%' height = '100%'>&nbsp;</td><td valign = 'top'>    
                    <a href='display.html'>Display</a>";
    if(!isset($_SESSION['loged'])){     
        echo "      <fieldset><legend>Log In</legend>
                    <center><table border = '0'>
                    <form action="log.php" method="post">
                    <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" /></td></tr>   
                    <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="pwd" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan = '2' align = 'center'><input type="submit" value="submit" /></td></tr>
                    </form>
                    </table></center>
                    </fieldset> ";
    }

    else{
        header(location:index.html);
        die();
    }
        echo "      </td><td width = '30%' height = '100%'>&nbsp;</td>  
                    </tr></table>       
    </body>
    </html>";
?>
```

Comment: As you can see from the syntax coloring, the unescaped quotes on line 12 terminate the string. Use `\"` to escape double quotes inside a double quote delimited string.

Comment: An advice. When you see errors like this, try to debug starting from the line mentioned going upwards. These are basic debugging which you would have already noticed had you used a Good PHPIDE software.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape your `"` in the strings.

It needs to be

```
<form action=\"log.php\" method=\"post\">
```

or better:

```
<form action='log.php' method='post'>
```

even better:

```
echo ' .... action="..." '
```

best:

```
 <?php php-code... ?>
 HTML-Code 
 <?php php-code... ?>
```

This of course in necessary for all the line of your code.

edit:

also, you need to write:

```
header('location:index.html');
```

(ty @Paul)

As stated in the comments, it's better if you don't echo such large html-segments. Especially when using double-quotes, the php-parser is doing a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: Or even better, don't `echo` such large segments of pure HTML at all.

Comment: And later it should be `header('location:index.html');`.

Answer (score 1):

Use single qoutes or escape the double quotes in this part:

```
<form action="log.php" method="post">
   <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" /></td></tr>   
   <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="pwd" /></td></tr>
   <tr><td colspan = '2' align = 'center'><input type="submit" value="submit" /></td></tr>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "      <fieldset><legend>Log In</legend>
                    <center><table border = '0'>
                    <form action="log.php" method="post">
                    <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" /></td></tr>   
                    <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="pwd" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan = '2' align = 'center'><input type="submit" value="submit" /></td></tr>
                    </form>
                    </table></center>
                    </fieldset> ";
```

Has a quoting problem.

Try

```
echo "      <fieldset><legend>Log In</legend>
                        <center><table border = '0'>
                        <form action='log.php' method='post'>
                        <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type='text' name='username' /></td></tr>   
                        <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='pwd' /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td colspan = '2' align = 'center'><input type='submit' value='submit' /></td></tr>
                        </form>
                        </table></center>
                        </fieldset> ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
<form action='log.php' method='post'>
```

You also have it several times in the following lines after that - change double quotes to single.

and also change:

```
header("location: index.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your first probleme is an escaping problem. When you do your echo you have to puy an \ for every " character

Comment: **When you do your echo you have to put an \ for every " character** wrong.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. he wrotes : echo "      <fieldset><legend>Log In</legend>
                    <center><table border = '0'>
                    <form action="log.php" method="post">
                    <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" /></td></tr>   
                    <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="pwd" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan = '2' align = 'center'><input type="submit" value="submit" /></td></tr>
                    </form>
                    </table></center>
                    </fieldset> ";

Comment: if you use `echo '';` you don't need to escape anything.

Comment: Completly agree with you. But the problem is the same he has to escape every ' in his string

Comment: erm no. `echo '<form action="log.php" method="post">';` you don't need to escape. Just need to use `'` for echo and `"` inside htmls or vice versa.

Comment: @itachi "if you use `echo '';` you don't need to escape anything." wrong... you need to escape single-quotes:-p